# Typescript doesn't figure out the generic

Tags: typescript, parsing, typescript-generics

I'm starting to learn about typescript and I tried to make an parser combinator library, at first types and generics where easy, but an issue appeared.

```js
// The generic T represents the value the parser returns
class Parser<T> {
    ...
}

// This function combines the two parsers in one tuple
function pair<P1 extends Parser<A>, P2 extends Parser<B>, A, B>(
  parser1: Parser<A>,
  parser2: Parser<B>
): Parser<{ fst: A, snd: B }> {
    ...
}

// Maps a Parser<A> to a Parser<B> through A => B
function map<P extends Parser<A>, F extends (a: A) => B, A, B>(
  parser: P, mapFn: F 
): Parser<B> {
    ...
}
```

Here is where I have the issue:

```js
// Like pair but the value of the parser is A, instead of {fst: A, snd: B}
function left<P1 extends Parser<A>, P2 extends Parser<B>, A, B>(
  parser1: P1,
  parser2: P2
): Parser<A> {
  return map(pair(parser1, parser2), (a: unknown): A => (a as {fst: R1, snd: R2}).fs );
}
```

The provided left function compiles but I don't understand why typescript cannot infer that the `unknown` should be `{fst: A, snd: B}`, is this a typescript issue or just me mistaking how typescript generics work.
Thanks in advance.

***EDIT***
Added reproducible playground:
Here is the link [reproducible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/es/play?#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)

Comment: are you talking about `a: unknown`? you've manually suppressed inference there by providing an explicit type. Inferring is done automatically

Comment: Yeah I'm refering to it, but even removing the type it says: `Object 'a' is of type 'unknown'`, the code I provided is a fix that works, but `a => a.fst` should work out of the box, doesn't it?

Comment: Ah, I see. Could you try to make a minimal reproducible example in typescript playground? I've seen a handful of bugs related to not inferring generics in a similar fashion (the typescript team is aware of it) - but this particular one may be a different issue. A playground link will help interactively diagnosing it.

Comment: @Chase done! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use Fewer Generics

When you have generic type parameters that are being inferred as `unknown`, one of the best things that you can do is to reduce the number of generics type parameters on your function and instead derive certain types from the others.

Sometimes this involves using built-in [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) like [`ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) to get the return type from the type of a function `T`.  We can also define our own utility types by using a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) along with `infer`/`extends`.

In your example there is actually a very simple solution where `A` and `B` are the only generic values.

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    callable: () => T;
    constructor(callable: () => T) {
        this.callable = callable;
    }
}

function map<A, B>(w: Wrapper<A>, mapFn: (a: A) => B): Wrapper<B> {
    return new Wrapper(() => mapFn(w.callable()));
}

function pair<A, B>(w1: Wrapper<A>, w2: Wrapper<B>): Wrapper<{fst: A, snd: B}> {
    return new Wrapper(() => ({fst: w1.callable(), snd: w2.callable()}));
}

function left<A, B>(w1: Wrapper<A>, w2: Wrapper<B>): Wrapper<A> {
    return map(pair(w1, w2), value => value.fst);
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/N5EP0N)

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I ended up doing, thanks for the explanation and the links very useful

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to explicitly infer Parser generic and map callback return type.

Example:

```js
// The generic T represents the value the parser returns
class Parser<T> { }

// This function combines the two parsers in one tuple
function pair<P1 extends Parser<A>, P2 extends Parser<B>, A, B>(
  parser1: Parser<A>,
  parser2: Parser<B>
): Parser<{ fst: A, snd: B }> {
  return null as any
}

type InferGeneric<T extends Parser<unknown>> = T extends Parser<infer R> ? R : never

function map<P extends Parser<A>, F extends (a: /** explicit infer generic */ InferGeneric<P>) => B, A, B>(
  parser: P, mapFn: F
): Parser<ReturnType<F>> /** Explicit ReturnType infer */ {
  return null as any
}


// Like pair but the value of the parser is A, instead of {fst: A, snd: B}
function left<P1 extends Parser<A>, P2 extends Parser<B>, A, B>(
  parser1: P1,
  parser2: P2
): Parser<A> {
  return map(pair(parser1, parser2), a => 42); // ok
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsFNQc2gO2gJwJYGMKhdADrgM5IAuhoJMoAbgIYA2ArrJbHrSsSjtCYyokIBYAFAZ6tQuQAKHLgB5wAPlABvUAF9RokBEhpyAM0aIMJNAHtEoDBYC2AIzTJyrCgHcLodp1TlnoFYsjHj00KLGpuZW3rRoKPLSAIyg0AAeJEgAJjJyqPIAgkoANKDSAEypGdm5vgkAQiWgBaWNABSioLF1SQBcZXkJRcWd3Vzl-bJ18o2iAJSTg-LqhoQk-S2ghIhZ-fWaKqqjuHwCoIiM9PSgkjeIAJ6iWiKiJPd4sACSiIaoAOJIVCYRRVTI7WoKEwAa0QFnciCUKgAvNh0mCcgNps5ftwAEoqAD8oFxoH6yGoqG0IkiZks1jstDwiVBNUxCmGoAAYizwaA2rR%20sAAFRCqqhTBoEigbGoeCA9BYIVgb44gHIBWJJRzUBIlT1UqbdqjHxcSalBl4TmIfqc%20aLaa43j8RDgd7QeScxGgYWigCiaXFGElxKdAldH2lP1lSrUx1D1guVxu5FoDyeVJ0YAAMmgoWw4twHIwpW46ExYBZDBQqCbZQZmqVnGtoLQsoEq6pVusG1sdntnjTotYwoYSIkUmjWVN2U0KjyMdP8o0Da0lB0RF1ayg%20mUkiMN2NUBMyuU7Wz8kVYweTs7QBa2ux4g-BnvDyhynNSrQdSoACwfgBub0wAsKEniAA)

Comment: This is black magic to me as a typescript newbie but thanks!! 

Comment: @cdecompilador generics are tricky sometimes ) Here https://catchts.com/callbacks and here https://catchts.com/chain-callbacks you can find more examples of using callbacks in TS. this is my personal blog

Comment: there's very interesting content, ty

Comment: @cdecompilador thanks, I'm trying to gather some interesting question & answers from stackoverflow about TypeScript

Comment: I was excited when I saw the awnser but sadly it doesn't work applied for example to the reproducible playground i provided, but anyway thanks I'm learning lot of things in your website

Comment: I've finally fixed with a better solution, changing the approach to the problem, I'm a rust programmer so im used to traits and the TS generic system have some limitations compared to traits

Comment: OMG, I'm a huge fan of Rust. I know a bit about traits. Hence you confessed that you are the Rust prograammer, could you please give me some links (I bet you have favourite) to Rust type system, how it works and ofcourse some good explanations about traits

Comment: This channel teaches: middle-high level rust, [JonGjengset](https://youtube.com/c/JonGjengset), the official rust book explains traits pretty well but the best way to understand them is using them, [super resource](https://github.com/osynavets/build-your-own-x-in-rust), here is the biggest resource, im doing something similar to the parser combinators in the link (one of the best resources). Hope it helps